# Different definitions of regularity of a measure

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

I was wondering what relations are between these different definitions of a regular measure? When are they equivalent?

There are two non-equivalent definitions from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure)

> Let $(X, T)$ be a topological space and let $\mathcal B$ be its Borel $σ$-algebra on $X$. Let $μ$ be a measure on $(X, Σ)$.
>
> $\mu$ is regular, if $\forall A \in \mathcal B$
>   $$
>     \mu (A) = \sup \{ \mu (F) | F \subseteq A, F \mbox{ closed} \}
> $$
>   and
>   $$
>     \mu (A) = \inf \{ \mu (G) | G \supseteq A, G \mbox{ open} \}.
> $$
>
> Alternatively, $\mu$ is regular, if $\forall A \in \mathcal B$ and  $\forall δ > 0$, there exists a closed set $F$ and an open set $G$ such that
>   $$
>     F \subseteq A \subseteq G
> $$
>   and
>   $$
>     \mu (G \setminus F) < \delta.
> $$
>
> The two definitions are equivalent if $\mu$ is finite (otherwise, the second definition is stronger).

Some authors (such as Dudley and Royden) require the set $F$ to be compact instead of closed.
From Royden's Real Analysis

> Let $\mu$ be a measure defined on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal M$ of subsets of $X$ and
>   suppose that $\mathcal M$ contains the Baire sets. $\mu$ is said to be
>   regular,  if $\forall E \in \mathcal M$
>   $$\mu(E) = \inf \{\mu(O) | E \subseteq O, O \text{ open}, O \in \mathcal M\}.$$
>   $$\mu(E) = \sup \{\mu(K) | K \subseteq E, K \text{ compact}, K \in \mathcal M\}.$$

From [encyclopediaofmath](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Measurable_mapping)

> On a Borel sigma algebra $\mathcal B$, a measure $\mu$ is called regular, if $$\forall A \in \mathcal B, \mu(A) = \sup \{\mu(F) |  F \subseteq A, F \text{ closed} \}$$

Thanks and regards!